# Why Query, TermQuery etc. are not longer implementing Serializable in Lucene 4.0?

Tags: java, serialization, lucene

I need to send a class containing Lucene elements such as `Query` over the network using EJB and of course this class need to be serialized. I marked my class as `Serializable` but it does not seems to be enough:

```
org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery is not Serializable
```

Indeed, when i read the javadoc of the last stable release of Lucene (4.0), i can see that `TermQuery` does not implement Serializable, `Query` neither. What i don't understand is why those classes used to implement `Serializable` in the last release (3.6.1), and why it's no longer the case?

Comment: You're asking in the wrong place. Try the Lucene mailing list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Mike McCandless, one of Lucene contributors](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/07/lucene-400-alpha-at-long-last.html) as well as Lucene 4 changelog say:

> All serialization code has been removed from Lucene's classes; you
>   must handle serialization at a higher level in your application.

The actual commits were done against JIRA issues [LUCENE-2908](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-2908) and [LUCENE-4037](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-4037). The description of the former issue says:

> We removed contrib/remote, but forgot to cleanup serialization hell
>   everywhere. this is no longer needed, never really worked (e.g. across
>   versions), and slows  development (e.g. i wasted a long time debugging
>   stupid serialization of  Similarity.idfExplain when trying to make a
>   patch for the scoring system).

Lucene is not alone thinking about throwing away serialization. For example, guava [considered](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=978) this, too.

Speaking about your problem - you should be able to always convert your query to a String representation (using `.toString()`) and back. Unless you do this million times a second, the overhead should be negligible.

Comment: I finally found out this change log. Thanks.

Comment: @mindas, I know the BooleanQuery.toString(), is there a way to convert that String back to BooleanQuery or query Object? Can you point me to the API or example?

Basically, I created a BooleanQuery which prints as +name:arun AND +favorite:stackoverflow, Is there a way to convert this back to Query object?

Comment: @ArunBC sure, just use `QueryParser` - feed your query string and you should get the same query object back.