# lucene: store queries on disk/persist queries

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I'm new to Lucene (4.7.1) so I apologise if this is a silly question.

What is the best way for me to store the queries to persist them across sessions? Should I leave them as strings in a DB or is it better to store them as Query objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store them as strings.

Queries are [no longer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html) `Serializable`,  although they [used to be](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html). Moreover, `String` representation should consume less storage space. More details are also available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699209/why-query-termquery-etc-are-not-longer-implementing-serializable-in-lucene-4-0).

Comment: My problem is that I need to save termqueries as well and it seems that there is no way to actually write this in a string format. I noticed that there is an api called org.apache.lucene.queryparser.xml. Is there any way for me to convert a Query object into xml?

Comment: Term query is actually very simple, e.g. `foo:bar` - simply means that field `foo` should be `bar`, as simple as that. Queries don't have XML representation, but you can take String format and put it in any XML you want.

Comment: What about for something like an author where I use a stringField then author:"Ken Follet" is a phrase search and not the same as using a TermQuery. So I can't simply save it as a String. I would need some indicator that this query is of type TermQuery.

Comment: Phrase queries enclose query string with quotes, so you just need to persist those quotes as well. Don't worry, when parsing such a string, Lucene will create `PhraseQuery`; same applies for all other types. You just have to trust `query.toString()` to provide you with the right format.

Comment: That's the problem. I don't want a phrasequery, I need a termquery for the author because it is a stringField. The phraseQuery fails with the quotes since it is tokenized.

Comment: It's probably better if you explain your problem in a separate post, preferably with code.

Comment: Its alright! I just needed to use a PerFieldAnalyzerWrapper. So now I can save it as a string and it won't use a tokenizer for the fields that are StringFields. Thanks for your help!