# How to Serialize Lucene Query or convert query to String and back to Query

Tags: java, solr, lucene, elasticsearch

Am using Lucene 4.7.2 version.

I have indexed some information and have create a UI to query on that interface. I create a BooleanQuery based on the user input,

example:

```
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery();
NumericRangeQuery<Integer> nrq = NumericRangeQuery.newIntRange("age", 20, 30, true, true);
bq.add(nrq, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

Term term = new Term("name", "einstein");
TermQuery termQuery = new TermQuery(term);
bq.add(termQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

System.out.println(bq.toString());
```

This prints,

```
+age[20 TO 30] AND name:einstein
```

Lucene runs on a separate server and it expects Query object to perform search. As the Query or BooleanQuery is not serializable, am trying to convert above String query across and convert it to Query/Boolean object.

I found [this idea of converting BooleanQuery.toString() to String and back to BooleanQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13699209/why-query-termquery-etc-are-not-longer-implementing-serializable-in-lucene-4-0) but am not able to find any API to convert String query to Query type.

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in the comment of linked question, just feed this String back to `QueryParser` and you should get identical `Query` objects back.

```
import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;

...

String queryString = "+age[20 TO 30] AND name:einstein";
Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_4_7, null, <yourAnalyzer>)
                   .parse(queryString);
```

Comment: Am using Lucene 4.7.1, none of the QueryParser constructor seem to accept String and there is no default constructor as well.

Comment: While it may work for the example query given, it is definitely not safe to assume that `Query.toString()` returns a string that will parse to an equivalent query using the `QueryParser`.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966287/lucene-4-2-stringfield), for example.

Comment: femtoRgon is right. I have used StringField and TextField, after creating the query for these field I convert it to String and pass it over the network to another method and when I try parsing the query from string with a analyzer I don't expect the StringField to be analyzed, but it happens. This is not good. Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably best if you open another question for this, or at least edit/update this one, providing isolated code which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
String queryString="Name:alivaliolah";
Query QueryObj=new QueryParser("", perFieldAnalyzor).parse(queryString);
TopDocs topDocFounded = searcher.search(QueryObj, hitsPerPage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question on the java users group for lucene.  What was recommended there were some Kryo libraries that worked for me:  http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/lucene-java-user/201603.mbox/browser.  I didn't have much luck with simply casting the toString output to a Query either, but the Kyro libraries overcome some of the issues with No-argument constructors and other serialization limitations

Adapting from James McKinley's suggestion there to write:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Output output = new Output(baos);
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false);
kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());
UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer.registerSerializers(kryo);
kryo.register(Arrays.asList("").getClass(), new
ArraysAsListSerializer());
kryo.register(BooleanClause.class);
kryo.register(Query.class);
kryo.register(Occur.class);
kryo.register(ToParentBlockJoinQuery.class);
kryo.register(QueryBitSetProducer.class);
SynchronizedCollectionsSerializer.registerSerializers(kryo);
kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, (List<BooleanClause>)
builder.build().clauses());
output.close();
String outputString =
Base64.encodeBase64String(baos.toByteArray());
```

Reading:

```
String inputString = (String) in.readObject();
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new
ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(inputString));
Input input = new Input(bais);
Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false);
kryo.setInstantiatorStrategy(new StdInstantiatorStrategy());
UnmodifiableCollectionsSerializer.registerSerializers(kryo);
kryo.register(Arrays.asList("").getClass(), new
ArraysAsListSerializer());
kryo.register(BooleanClause.class);
kryo.register(Query.class);
kryo.register(Occur.class);
kryo.register(ToParentBlockJoinQuery.class);
kryo.register(QueryBitSetProducer.class);
SynchronizedCollectionsSerializer.registerSerializers(kryo);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<BooleanClause> queryObject = (List<BooleanClause>)
kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
input.close();
builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
for (BooleanClause clause : queryObject) {
builder.add(clause);
}
```

I have my doubts about the need to register all the classes.