# Is there a SolrJ query builder?

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud, solr5, solr-query-syntax

Using solr 5.2.0 was wondering is there a query builder API/Jar/Ckient similar to Elasticsearch query builder API or do we have to bassically do String Kungfu to build queries in Solr?

Comment: Is http://www.solrtutorial.com/lucene-query-builder.html what you're looking for ?

Comment: Any API/SDK/jar

Comment: I guess we can use the lucene query builder classes directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, in SolrJ there is no such thing as a Builder for the query that goes into the `q`-Parameter.

BUT: As Solr already operates on Lucene, we can as well use the Lucene [QueryBuilder](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/util/QueryBuilder.html). The resulting Query objects (e.g. [PhraseQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/PhraseQuery.html)) have a `toString()` method that provides you with the query string you would otherwise have to assemble by hand.

Comment: @seven.windisch can you post some examples

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841494/how-to-serialize-lucene-query-or-convert-query-to-string-and-back-to-query someone asked the question the other way round (Querystring to query object). The question contains a nice example for our case here.

Comment: Be aware, that a lucene Query instance works with Terms but on client side you have not FieldTypes/analyzer. Possible the flexible QueryParser is the better choise [QueryNode](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_5_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/core/nodes/QueryNode.html). But I see no way to build queries with nested queries with this syntaxTree neither.

Answer (score -1):

You might want to [use SolrQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_5_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/SolrQuery.html)

```
  SolrQuery solrQuery=new SolrQuery();
  solrQuery.set("q",query);
  solrQuery.set("rows",5000);
  QueryResponse response=solrServers.query(solrQuery);
```

For more examples please refer this [link](http://www.javased.com/?api=org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrQuery)

Comment: I know. But the query still has to be build using string concatenation... I'm looking for a builder style API. It seems spring has something, but don't want to use spring. So far it seems it doesn't exist.